# Handling data from csv file with Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I know Python is almost made for these kind of purposes, but I am really struggling to understand how I get access to specific values in the dataset, and I tried both with pandas and csv modules. It is probably a matter of syntax. Here's the thing: I have a csv file in the form of

```
Nation, Year, No. of refugees
Afghanistan,2013,6657
Albania,2013,199
Algeria,2013,91
Angola,2013,47
Armenia,2013,156
...
...
Afghanistan,2012,6960
Albania,2012,157
Algeria,2012,67
Angola,2012,43
Armenia,2012,143
...
```

and so on. What I would like to do is to get the total amount of refugees per year, i.e. selecting all the rows with a certain year and summing all the elements in the related "no. of refugees" column. I managed to do this:

```
import csv

with open('refugees.csv', 'r') as f:
    d_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    headers = d_reader.fieldnames
    print headers

    #2013
    list2013=[]
    for line in d_reader:
        if (line['Year']=='2013'):
            list2013.append(line['Refugees'])
    list2013=map(int,list2013) #I have str values in my file
    ref13=sum(list2013)
```

but I am looking for a more elegant (and, above all, iterative) solution. Moreover, if I perform that procedure multiple times for different years, I always get 0: it works for 2013 only, not sure why.

Edit: I tried this as well, without success, but I think this could be totally wrong:

```
import csv
refugees_dict={}
a=range(2005,2014)
a=map(str, a)
with open('refugees.csv', 'r') as f:
    d_reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    for element in a:
        for line in d_reader:
            if (line['Year']==element):
                print 'hello!'
                temp_list=[]
                temp_list.append(line['Refugees'])
                temp_list=map(int, temp_list)
                refugees_dict[a]=sum(temp_list)

print refugees_dict
```

The next step of my work will involve further studies on the dataset, eg I am probably gonna need to access data nation-wise instead of year-wise, and I really appreciate any hint so I understand how to manipulate data.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `it works for 2013 only, not sure why`, because you hardcoded `if (line['Year']=='2013')`, maybe?....., also were you not able to load this into a pandas data frame?

Comment: Instead of csv, since you have pandas listed in your tags, use 'import pandas as pd' and then `dataframe = pd.read_csv("refugees.csv")` or `dataframe = pd.read_csv("refugees.csv", header=None)` if you don't want the headers.

Comment: Dmitry, of course I edited the code properly each time. I am a noob, but not completely stupid :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you tagged pandas in the question, here's a pandas solution to getting the number of refugees per year.

Let's say my input csv looks like this (note that I've eliminated the extra space before the column names):

```
Nation,Year,No. of refugees
Afghanistan,2013,6657
Albania,2013,199
Algeria,2013,91
Angola,2013,47
Armenia,2013,156
Afghanistan,2012,6960
Albania,2012,157
Algeria,2012,67
Angola,2012,43
Armenia,2012,143
```

You can read that into a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

You can then get the total like this:

```
df.groupby(['Year']).sum()
```

This gives:

```
        No. of refugees
 Year
2012               7370
2013               7150
```

Comment: Seems like the simplest solution! I am still familiarizing with python and pandas, seen your solution I can tell that my question was quite a noob one, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To sum by year you can try this:

```
f = open('file.csv').readlines()

f = [i.strip('\n').split(',') for i in f]

years = {i[1]:0 for i in f}

for i in f:
    years[i[1]] += int(i[-1])
```

Now, you have a dictionary that has the sum of all the refugees by year.

To access nation-wise:

```
nations = {i[0]:0 for i in f}

for i in f:
    nations[i[0]] += int(i[-1])
```

Comment: CSV parsing is hairy. I'd use the `csv` module in general case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
from collections import defaultdict
by_year = defaultdict(int)  # a dict that has a 0 under every key.
```

and then

```
by_year[line['year']] += int(line['Refugees'])
```

Now you can just look at `by_year['2013']` and see your sum (same for other years).

Comment: thanks a lot, seems useful for a nation-wise analysis as well.

Comment: you're welcome. btw with this kind of data, you  might be better served by a relational database and SQL. any major RDBMS has no trouble importing CSVs.